# parse list on page getting by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, parsing

I have dropdown country, State and city. I wrote controller and GET list of State by country Id witch I add like that

```
<option value="1"> Afghanistan </option>
<option value="2"> Aland Islands </option>
...
```

Controller retrieve list of states I see it in browser console(Response)

```
[{id: 2954, name: "Mogilev Region"}, {id: 2955, name: "Gomel Region"},…]
0: {id: 2954, name: "Mogilev Region"}
1: {id: 2955, name: "Gomel Region"}
2: {id: 2956, name: "Grodno Region"}
3: {id: 2957, name: "Minsk Region"}
4: {id: 2958, name: "Minsk"}
5: {id: 2959, name: "Brest Region"}
6: {id: 2960, name: "Vitebsk Region"}
```

My Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/country")
public @ResponseBody List<States>  getStates(@RequestParam("countryId") Long countryId){
    List<States> stateList = countryRepo.findAllById(countryId);
    return stateList;
}
```

Question is how parse information to select? I try some various code nothing work.

```
    $("#countryId").change(function () {
        var countryId = $("#countryId").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/country?countryId='+countryId,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (states) {
                var html = '';
                var len = states.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + states[i].id + '">'
                        + states[i].name
                        + '</option>';
                }
                $('#stateop').html(html);

            }
        });
    });
```

States show one long string like that: "undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined".
How parse response properly?

Comment: This question does not appear to be related to Thymeleaf. Can you edit the question's title, and remove the `thymeleaf` tag - or else clarify why/how this is Thymeleaf related?

Comment: why your `dataType: 'html'` ? isn't that should be `json` ? Also you need to convert your list to json and then send it back to ajax.

Comment: The problem was in dataType: 'html' that should be 'json' like @Swati mentioned. Also to properly render there  should be  $("#stateop").empty(); after "success: function (states) {" line.